# Google Sheets | get capacity from title and move to next column

Tags: google-sheets

in Google Sheet I have  title example:

```
Babaria Exotic Bronze Tanning Jelly Spf0 Coconut 300ml
```

From this I need get `300ml` and move to the next column

result: `column1: Babaria Exotic Bronze Tanning Jelly Spf0 Coconut 300ml  column2: 300ml`

For better understand I share here full file.

Can anyone have time to help me show me this on file? Thanks for help!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Y9BNcAOTGegHzvYLXwSO2IJN0NMqmsC7ZsM9bughVE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've placed my answer into your sheet. Simple RegEx extract:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(F2:F,"\d+ml")))
```